# Apply git patch to another repo where the file has a different starting condition

Tags: xml, git, patch

If I have two similarly structured but not identical files in two git repositories, and I make a patch serial to change a value in one of them, is it possible to apply that patch to the other?

For example, if I make a patch serial to change the value for "fish" to from 6 to 10 in the first file below in one repo, could I apply that patch to the other repo to also set "fish" to 10 there, despite it having a different starting value for "fish"?

```
<eggs>5</eggs>
<fish>6</fish>
<peas>7</peas>
```

```
<eggs>5</eggs>
<fish>2</fish>
<peas>7</peas>
```

Comment: The short answer is no: `git apply` works on a line-by-line basis and since `<fish>6</fish>` never matches `<fish>2</fish>`, no amount of fiddling will let `git apply` change this to `<fish>10</fish>`. (Patch formats tend not to deal all that well with structured data like XML in the first place.)

Comment: If you *do* have the *common ancestor* version of the file, though, the `--3way` option will let Git reconstruct the original `<fish>2</fish>`-to-`<fish>10</fish>` change, apply that to the original file, and use the merge code, as [Özgür Murat Sağdıçoğlu said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74108618/1256452).

Answer (score 1):

After creating a patch with `git format-patch` in the first repo, you can apply the patch to the second repo using --3way option like:

```
git am --3way < changes.patch
```

`--3way` will do a three-way merge if there are conflicts. Then you can resolve the conflict on the "`fish`" line as usual such as running `git merge-tool`.

From the git manual:

> --3way
>
> Attempt 3-way merge if the patch records the identity of blobs it is supposed to apply to and we have those blobs available locally,
> possibly leaving the conflict markers in the files in the working tree
> for the user to resolve. This option implies the --index option unless
> the --cached option is used, and is incompatible with the --reject
> option. When used with the --cached option, any conflicts are left at
> higher stages in the cache.

Comment: This depends on (i.e., requires) having the *common ancestor* version of the file in both repositories. It's not clear from the OP's question whether that would be the case here.

Comment: @torek you are right! I missed that point. 3way merge can only work with a common ancestor. So this solution can only work if there is a common parent blob (or commit?) and that blob is identified in the patch. I assume then the patch should be created against the common ancestor. So 2 way merge and resolving conflict manually is the way to go in most cases?

Comment: You need only the blob object (as that's what shows up in the `index:` line in the patch). If it's absent, `-3` has no effect and the patch gets rejected (put in `.rej` file with `--reject`, otherwise you just get "does not apply").